# Multilanguage website change language based on ip and seo

Tags: internationalization, seo, geolocation, multilingual

I have a multilaguage website(primary language is Greek and secondary is English).
I am thinking to create a script in order to display Greek language by default only at Greece and Cyprus and for other countries to be English.That could be easily done by ip.

For the end users that would be great! What about the search engines.Google i think that it crawls websites with USA ip which means that it will be able to see only the English version of the website.
Is there any alternative solutions to handle the problem of SEO?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First off, doing geolocation of the client IP alone is an inferior method for determining which language to show to a new user. IP address locations can be very unreliable, especially when the user is using a cellular data connection.

Instead, use what the client actually tells you is their language via the HTTP `Accept-Language` header. Most browsers set that correctly based on the user's choices which they decided upon during browser installation (or changed it in their browser preferences soon afterwards).

Once you've used `Accept-Language` to make a good first estimate at the right language content to show, you should also offer the user a way to make a different choice in your website. Once a user hits a link to see the site in another language, store that choice in a cookie or their account preferences so that you'll show the same language next time they visit. Remember that their next visit might be from their laptop in another country.

Tip for others thinking about doing this: **avoid flags as a way to change language**. There is no 1-to-1 flag-to-language correlation, and you risk further confusing or offending some users. Offer a language choice in the target language (for example offer a link with "En Español" for Spanish).

As long as you offer links to choose other languages ("En Español", "In English", etc) then search engines will trawl those links too and your SEO rank will improve accordingly. In fact, having selectable **multilingual content is a great way to improve your SEO rank** because it can lead to more incoming links, as well as a recognition by the Googles of the world that you have more unique content. FYI, offering links that auto-translate content on the fly (using something like Google Translate) does not improve your SEO rank, because it's considered the same content.

Comment: To add one thing for the SEO, use the new multilingual sitemap for Google and it will know exactly what you are trying to do - http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site.html

Comment: "IP address locations can be very unreliable" - and country is only loosely correlated with preferred language anyway.